# rxjs/Subject.d.ts error : Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I extracted sample template code from [this tutorial](https://github.com/gopinav/Angular-2-Tutorials) and did below two steps to get started -

1. `npm install // worked fine and created node_modules folder with all dependencies`
2. `npm start`
   // failed with below error-

   ```
   node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' 
     incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
     Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
     Type '<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable  
     to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
     Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
     Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
     npm ERR! errno 2
   ```

I see that in the subject.d.ts declaration of lift is as below -

```
 lift<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<T>;
```

And in Observable.ts it is defined as below-

```
 lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R> {
```

Note:-
1. I am new to Angular2 and trying to get hold of things.

2. The error might be due to incompatible definitions of lift method
3. I read through this [github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2073)
4. If I need to install some different version of rxjs then please tell how to uninstall and install the correct rxjs.

**Edit1:** 
I might be a bit late in responding here but I still get the same error even after using *typescript 2.3.4* or *rxjs 6 alpha*. Below is my package.json,

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "6.0.0-alpha.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.4",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16593

Comment: A [_little_ clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44869944/1042705)

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in [rxjs@5.4.2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#542-2017-07-05).

Answer (score 72):

As per [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16593) you need update typescript 2.3.4 or rxjs 6 alpha

go the your package.json file in your project update typescript or rxjs version.
Example

```
"typescript": "2.3.4"
```

do `npm install`

**update(06/29/2017):-**

As per the comments typescript `"2.4.0"` working.

Comment: `"typescript": "^2.3.4"` will match 2.4.1 and 2.4 is the version that exposes the problem with RxJS.

Comment: Replaced typescript version to "2.4.0" worked for me.

Comment: I second that it has to be exactly "2.3.4" - "^2.3.4" didn't work for me.

Comment: combination of `"typescript": "2.3.0"` and `"rxjs": "5.4.1"` worked for me

Comment: @Jonnysai sorry, I take back what I said. Project compiled, but I got a runtime error and downgraded to 2.3.4 . More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44556137

Comment: Do we want something like ```"typescript": "~2.3.4"```? In case a patch-level change is released?

Comment: if you are using nom 5 try deleting the package-lock.json and node_modules before running "npm i"

Comment: Downvoted because this answer doesn't seems to be updated with the info on the 5.4.2 rxjs version which fixes this.

Answer (score 25):

As others have pointed out this issue came about as a consequence of the stricter type checking of generics introduced in TypeScript 2.4. This exposed an inconsistency in a RxJS type definition and was consequently fixed in [RxJS version 5.4.2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#542-2017-07-05). **So ideal solution is to just upgrade to 5.4.2.**

If you for some reason cannot upgrade to 5.4.2 you should instead use Alan Haddad's solution of augmenting the type declaration to fix it for your own project. I.e. add this snippet to your app:

```
// TODO: Remove this when RxJS releases a stable version with a correct declaration of `Subject`.
import { Operator } from 'rxjs/Operator';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

declare module 'rxjs/Subject' {
  interface Subject<T> {
    lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R>;
  }
}
```

His solution will leave no other side-effects and is thus great. Alternatively proposed solutions have more side-effects for your project setup and thus are less ideal:

- turn off the stricter generic checks with compiler flag `--noStrictGenericChecks`. This will however make it less strict for your own app, which you can do, but might introduce inconsistent type definitions like it did in this RxJS instance which in turn might introduce more bugs in your app.
- Not checking the types in libraries with flag --skipLibCheck set to true. This is not ideal either as you might not get some type errors reported.
- Upgrading to RxJS 6 Alpha - given that there are breaking changes this might break your app in badly documented ways, seeing as it's still in alpha. Additionally if you have other dependencies like Angular 2+ this might not really be a supported option, breaking the framework itself now or down the line. Which I think is an even harder issue to solve.

Answer (score 24):

An admitted band-aid approach is to add the following to your tsconfig.json file until the RxJS folks decide what they want to do about the error when using TypeScript 2.4.1 :

```
"compilerOptions": {

    "skipLibCheck": true,

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked. I tried lots of other things but I guess this error is related with wrong packages with wrong version doesn't support each other...

Comment: I think its not a good idea to disable or suppress All LibCheck.

Comment: I suggested the same thing on the [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17800#issuecomment-311675622)

Comment: @Jonnysai since you down't own that code, supressing lib check is fine in the short term as you can file issues with the libraries, and then continue your own development work. You can file your own issue and link to their issue, and when their types get fixed you can take the supression off.

Comment: The real solution should **not** be to `skipLibCheck`. If you're doing that, you're potentially glazing over other problems.

A better solution is `noStrictGenericChecks` until RxJS gets updated.

Comment: `skipLibCheck` doesn't work the way you would expect, per documentation on `compilerOptions`, it skips type checking for all `*.d.ts` files, not just those under `node_modules`, which could be problematic if you have internal libraries outputting `.d.ts` files for type checking :(

Answer (score 18):

You can temporarily work around the issue by using [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

The following code resolved the issue for me. Once RxJS has a stable release that does not exhibit this issue, it should be removed.

```
// augmentations.ts
import {Operator} from 'rxjs/Operator';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

// TODO: Remove this when a stable release of RxJS without the bug is available.
declare module 'rxjs/Subject' {
  interface Subject<T> {
    lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R>;
  }
}
```

While it is perhaps ironic that RxJS itself makes such heavy use of this technique to describe its own shape, it is actually generally applicable to an array of problems.

While there are certainly limits and rough edges, part of what makes this technique powerful is that we can use it to enhance existing declarations making them more type safe without forking and maintain the entire file.

Comment: where do you add or import this file?

Comment: add it anywhere in your project such that it will be picked up by the compiler. If you're using explicit file lists make sure it's included. Otherwise it should get picked up automatically as long as it's not above the tsconfig.json file

Comment: I tried this, as it seemed the least disruptive thing to do. Worked fine.

Comment: Looks like the best temporary solution, I put this on top of my root app.module ( Angular 4) and also the CDK erros was gone

Comment: I am unclear about how to add the file. The question concerns an Angular2 app. I added it the app folder that contains app.module.ts -- but still have the error. Do I need to import the module somewhere? And how would I do this? I can't "import {rxjs/Subject}".

Comment: I figured out how to add the file -- "import 'rxjs/Subject';" (without the "from" or curly braces) in app.component.ts.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz sorry for not responding earlier, it's very odd that you have to do that. If it was in your source directory it should be picked up automatically unless you're using an explicit file list

Comment: Actually it turns out that the augmentations.ts code is not fixing the problem for me with or without the import statement. I wasn't testing it properly. I need to use the "noStrictGenericChecks" compiler option.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz are you sure you have the same problem? Also, rxjs is on version 5.5.2 at this point and I think they fixed the problem. Just upgrade.

Comment: I have rxjs@5.5.0 installed. But I am using videogular2 which has a dependency on rxjs@5.1.0.

Comment: sounds like you have a different problem.

Comment: The full error message I get is: ERROR in C:/GOVMEETING/ANGULARCLI/BrowserAppNew/node_modules/videogular2/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts (16,22): Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.

Comment: You said that videogular2 has a dependency on rxjs. So you have multiple versions of the library and from the error, that is the one giving you the trouble. Try to install Rxjs under "peerDepenedencies" –

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am also using videogular2 and am having the same problem as John. His solution seems to be working for me. However installing Rxjs under peerDependencies did not work. I am using rxjs 5.5.2. Is there another way to do this so Im not running multiple versions of rxjs?

Comment: @JaredWhipple That is a serious issue and has implications for much more than typechecking. You can use `"paths"` in `tsconfig.json` to explicitly specify where `"rxjs"` and `"rxjs/*"` should resolve for typechecking. However, having multiple versions is likely to cause runtime issues. Even if you don't use `instanceof` and other such tests, your deps may be less principled. Best thing to do is to open an issue with videogular2 suggesting changing RxJS to a peer dependency.

Answer (score 9):

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/common": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/core": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/forms": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/http": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.1",
"@angular/router": "^4.3.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "^5.4.2",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "^6.0.42",
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"protractor": "~4.0.13",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "^4.3.0",
"typescript": "^2.3.4",
"typings": "^1.3.2"
}
```

**in package.json** `"rxjs": "^5.4.2",` and **"typescript": "^2.3.4",** then **npm install** and **ng serve** its working.

Answer (score 8):

Just a little bit of detail, in an attempt to put in my two cents.

The problem arises when we upgrade *Typescript* to the latest version, which by now was [*TypeScript 2.4.1*](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/8/6D8381B0-03C1-4BD2-AE65-30FF0A4C62DA/2.4.1-TS-release-dev14update3-20170626.1/TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe), [ "as we love the upgrades : )" ],  and as [mentioned by @*Jonnysai*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44793989/1042705) in his answer and the link provided there, there is a detailed discussion regarding the problem and its fixes.

So, what *worked* for me was:
1. I had to ***Un***install *TypeScript 2.4.1* first, by going to *Control Panel* > *Programs and Features...*
2. Install, afresh, [*TypeScript 2.4.0*](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/8/6D8381B0-03C1-4BD2-AE65-30FF0A4C62DA/2.4.0-TS-release-dev14update3-20170608.3/TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe), and then make sure, in `package.json` file,  you have this
[image]
configuration, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44858294/1042705) in a rather shorter detail.

 You can download *TypeScript 2.4.0* from [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/8/6D8381B0-03C1-4BD2-AE65-30FF0A4C62DA/2.4.0-TS-release-dev14update3-20170608.3/TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe), *for Visual Studio 2015*

Comment: This worked very simply with no "workarounds".  I'm not sure this matters but my rxjs  was  "5.0.1" and I did not change that, all seems fine though. Thanks for your two cents - it helped me!

Comment: I also have this problem using Typescript 2.3.4. So it seems not correct that the problem arises because of upgrading to 2.4.1. The current angular-cli installs 2.3.4 because it says that it requires <2.4.0.

Answer (score 5):

You can temporarily use the `--noStrictGenericChecks` flag to get around this in TypeScript 2.4.

This is `--noStrictGenericChecks` on the command line, or just `"noStrictGenericChecks": true` in the `"compilerOptions"` field in `tsconfig.json`.

Keep in mind, RxJS 6 will have this corrected.

See this similar question: [How do I get around this error in RxJS 5.x in TypeScript 2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810195/how-do-i-get-around-this-error-in-rxjs-5-x-in-typescript-2-4/44810196#44810196)

Comment: where do you put the flag?

Answer (score 4):

Add **"noStrictGenericChecks": true** in **tsconfig.json** file under **"compilerOptions"** node as shown in below image & build application. I have faced same error after adding this error resolved.
 [image]

Answer (score 3):

Please change the following line of `Subject.d.ts` file:

```
lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<T>;
```

to:

```
lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R>;
```

The return type should probably be `Observable<R>` rather than `Observable<T>`

Answer (score 3):

Keep the noStrictGeneric option true in tsconfig.config file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noStrictGenericChecks": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found same problem and I solved it by using **"rxjs": "5.4.1"**, **"typescript": "~2.4.0"** and adding **"noStrictGenericChecks": true** into tsconfig.json.

Answer (score 1):

RxJS 6 will have this fixed, but as a temporary workaround, you can use the `noStrictGenericChecks` compiler option.

In `tsconfig.json`, put it in `compilerOptions` and set it to true.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noStrictGenericChecks": true
    }
}
```

On the command line it's `--noStrictGenericChecks`.

Why it's happening:

TypeScript 2.4 has a strictness change, and Subject isn't lifting to the correct Observable. The signature really should have been

> (operator: Operator) => Observable

This will be fixed in RxJS 6.

Answer (score 1):

GO to Package.json file and modify the below configuration

```json
...
  "rxjs": "5.4.1",
  "typescript": "~2.4.0"
...
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Using the above alone did not help, however, using the following approach:
[How do I get around this “Subject incorrectly extends Observable” error in TypeScript 2.4 and RxJs 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810195/how-do-i-get-around-this-subject-incorrectly-extends-observable-error-in-types?noredirect=1&lq=1)

solved the issues. It is also mentioned there that the issue has been fixed in RxJs 6, so this is more of a temporary fix, which helped me in successfully running this great example (which compiled before but gave the error during load time):
[Angular 4 application development with Bootstrap 4 and TypeScript](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1366/angular-4-app-typescript-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling rxjs -> npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save

Answer (score 0):

Now we dont need the ionic-native module - we only need @ionic-native/core.
Run

```
npm uninstall ionic-native --save
```

It will solve Your Problem..

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
"noStrictGenericChecks": true
```

to your tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

thanks the answer of zmag and Rahul Sharma, it works!
@zmag @Rahul Sharma

```
  "rxjs": "5.4.1",
  "typescript": "~2.4.0"
```

my problem is as follow:

`typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts:3:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier`

Make changes as.

GO to Package.json file and modify the below configuration

```
  "rxjs": "5.4.1",
  "typescript": "~2.4.0"
```

Answer (score -3):

yes the problem was with 
TypeScript 2.4.1
I just uninstalled this from Control panel and it works for me as Visual Studio 2017 already has this.