# Webpack build not updating contents on Apache server

Tags: apache, angular, typescript, webpack

I have an Angular2 webpack project which works fine in local(webpack-dev-server) but once I deploy to my server(Apache), and run "npm run build", the build does not get updated(no errors shown).I tried removing my dist folder but still no change.No changes made to html are shown(it was working perfectly fine before)

webpack.config.js -->

```
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/main'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts','.tsx', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'],
                exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [
                    'raw-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                        options: {
                            // Or array of paths
                            resources: [
                                './src/assets/sharedStyles/_variables.scss',
                                './src/assets/sharedStyles/_mixins.scss'
                            ]
                        },
                    }
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
            { test: /\.(eot|ttf|wav|mp3|pdf|woff2|woff|png|svg|gif)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader' }
        ]
    },
    // plugins
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            __dirname // location of your src
        ),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: './src/assets',
            to: './assets',
            copyUnmodified: true,
            force: true
        }])
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "src/"),
        compress: true,
        port: 3000,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        inline: true
    }
};
```

package.json-->

```
{
    "name": "App",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "typings install",
        "typings": "typings",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --public --port 3000 --hot --host 0.0.0.0",
        "build": "webpack",
        "build-prod": "webpack -p"
    },
    "licenses": [
        {
            "type": "MIT",
            "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
        }
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/common": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/forms": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "^4.1.2",
        "@angular/upgrade": "4.1.2",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "d3": "^4.9.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
        "jquery": "2.x.x",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.10.3",
        "jquery-ui-npm": "^1.12.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
        "primeui": "^4.1.15",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
        "rxjs": "5.1.0",
        "systemjs": "0.19.39",
        "typescript": "^2.4.1",
        "zone.js": "0.7.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
        "@types/jquery": "^2.0.33",
        "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.4",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.3",
        "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
        "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
        "google-maps": "^3.2.1",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
        "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.6",
        "ng2-datetime": "1.2.1",
        "ng2-popover": "0.0.13",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
        "primeng": "^4.1.0-rc.2",
        "primeui": "^4.1.15",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "sass-resources-loader": "^1.2.0",
        "smartadmin-plugins": "^1.0.15",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
        "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
        "ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "typings": "2.1.0",
        "webpack": "^2.2.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a "hard" refresh or clearing your cache and trying to load the site?

Comment: You do build your projects on your production server?!