# Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T> Nativescript navigation drawer error

Tags: typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

**# This is the error I am facing now:**

i downloaded navigation drawer sample using npm (https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-angular-drawer-template). but it gives the following error.

````
dhrn@dhrn-Inspiron-5548:~/NativeApp/Supervisor$ tns run android

Searching for devices...
iTunes is not available for this operating system. You will not be able to work with connected iOS devices.
Executing before-prepare hook from /home/dhrn/NativeApp/Supervisor/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 2.4.1
node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.

node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/properties/properties.d.ts(48,14): error TS2559: Type 'Property<T, U>' has no properties in common with type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<U>'.

node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/properties/properties.d.ts(59,14): error TS2559: Type 'CoercibleProperty<T, U>' has no properties in common with type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<U>'.

Unable to apply changes on device: 192.168.56.101:5555. Error is: TypeScript compiler failed with exit code 1.


```
**My configuration:**

```
{
    "description": "NativeScript Application",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
    "readme": "NativeScript Application",
    "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
    "nativescript": {
        "id": "org.nativescript.supervisor",
        "tns-android": {
            "version": "3.1.1"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
        "nativescript-angular": "~3.0.0",
        "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^2.0.1",
        "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
        "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "~5.2.0",
        "tns-core-modules": "~3.0.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-traverse": "6.18.0",
        "babel-types": "6.18.0",
        "babylon": "6.13.1",
        "lazy": "1.0.11",
        "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.4.0",
        "typescript": "^2.3.2",
        "zone.js": "~0.7.2"
    }
}
````

**Project Configuration:**

```
dhrn@dhrn-Inspiron-5548:~/NativeApp/Supervisor$ tns info 
All NativeScript components versions information
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information   │
│ nativescript     │ 3.1.1           │ 3.1.1          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-core-modules │ 3.1.0           │ 3.1.0          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-android      │ 3.1.1           │ 3.1.1          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-ios          │                 │ 3.1.0          │ Not installed │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

**Please kindly help me to fix this issue .**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get around this "Subject incorrectly extends Observable" error in TypeScript 2.4 and RxJS 5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810195/how-do-i-get-around-this-subject-incorrectly-extends-observable-error-in-types)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810195/how-do-i-get-around-this-subject-incorrectly-extends-observable-error-in-types. You can get around this with the `noStrictGenericChecks` compiler option.

Answer (score 12):

There are some [issues with Microsoft/Typescript 2.4.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16593) update.

From the discussion in this issues page, it seems you need to use

[image]

configuration. Make sure, you *actually* have [*typescript 2.4.0*](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/8/6D8381B0-03C1-4BD2-AE65-30FF0A4C62DA/2.4.0-TS-release-dev14update3-20170608.3/TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe) installed.
You can download it from [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/8/6D8381B0-03C1-4BD2-AE65-30FF0A4C62DA/2.4.0-TS-release-dev14update3-20170608.3/TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe)

Comment: I needed to use typescript 2.3.4

Comment: @jim in that case make sure you have it as `"typescript": "2.3.4"` not as `"typescript": "^2.3.4"` or `"typescript": "~2.3.4"`, Refer to [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16593), and again you _should_ have this particular version installed

Comment: i'm getting new error ->
node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/properties/properties.d.ts(48,14): error TS2559: Type 'Property<T, U>' has no properties in common with type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<U>'.

node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/properties/properties.d.ts(59,14): error TS2559: Type 'CoercibleProperty<T, U>' has no properties in common with type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<U>'.

Comment: @DharanG are you sure you are not referencing version `Typescipt 2.4.1` as of now ..?  Make sure the version number doesn't contain `"^ or ~ "` in `package.json` (for both `rxjs:` and `typescript:` ), in that case it will be upgrading and/or pointing to their higher versions, and not to the specific. Take [a look here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4498)

Answer (score 1):

try this **tsconfig.json**

RxJS 6 will have this fixed, but as a temporary workaround, you can use the noStrictGenericChecks compiler option

**"noStrictGenericChecks": true**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": true 
  }
}
```