# ng2-opd-popup issue with angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I installed ng2-opd-popup module and tried to import if from app.module.ts by importing  "PopupModule.forRoot()". It produces following error.

[image: It produce following error.]

I am using typescript version as 2.4.2 and rxjs version as 5.4.2.
I tried to fix it using given solutions in [rxjs/Subject.d.ts error : Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793859/rxjs-subject-d-ts-error-class-subjectt-incorrectly-extends-base-class-obs?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [How do I get around this "Subject incorrectly extends Observable" error in TypeScript 2.4 and RxJS 5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810195/how-do-i-get-around-this-subject-incorrectly-extends-observable-error-in-types?noredirect=1&lq=1). Both of solutions didn't work for me. Can anyone give any suggetions to fix this?

I applied ng2-opd-popup module here to have popup window by using button click event as my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

in `tsconfig.json` file add following code snippet

```
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
     noStrictGenericChecks : true
  }
}
```

it might help you to survive