# Compilation error from Angular and typescript in VS 2015 MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am new to Angular and taking baby step to implement in `ASP.Net` MVC project. I downloaded the Angular quick start from github and latest typescript **v 3.2.2.0** for visual studio 2015 update 3. I am getting the following error Property lift in the type 'Subject is not assignable tot he same property in base type Observable' .

```
other version used:
npm -v is 6.4.1
node -v is 10.15.2
```

The package.json that I downloaded from github had a reference to the older version version. Attached is the `package.json` file i am using.

I have my `npm` running and was able to host the website through lift-server.

> error TS2416: Property 'lift' in type 'Subject' is not assignable
>   to the same property in base type 'Observable'. Type '(operator:
>   Operator) => Observable' is not assignable to type
>   '(operator: Operator) => Observable'. Type 'Observable'
>   is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Type 'T' is not assignable
>   to type 'R'

Please help.

[Error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoxgN.png)

```js
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: Cindy, Please add Package.json.  It's likely it is out of date.

Comment: I was thinking the same too. I edited the post to include the package.json code. What updates should i do to proceed. Also added other tools tools versions used npm(v6.4.1) and node(v10.15.2)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44810195/how-do-i-get-around-this-subject-incorrectly-extends-observable-error-in-types Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade with:

`npm install --save rxjs@^6.4.0` 
this issue should have been fixed in RxJS 6.

Comment: Angular 4 is meant to work with RxJS 5.  The highest the user should go is 5.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here.
First, your Typescript is on the latest version.  I'm not sure even Angular 7 supports Typescript 3.2.2.  I think they will when Angular 8 is released shortly.
Second, your Angular packages are way out of date.  You should update to Angular 7 if possible.
Third, Visual Studio can sometimes get picky about your ts config.  If the above two don't work please post your ts config so we can look at it.  I build Angular Applications from the Web Form template in VS 2017.  I use the Angular CLI instead of any VS Extension.  If you want more details let me know.

Here's a package.json from a project I started recently:

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"d3": "^4.10.2",
"d3-array": "^1.2.1",
"d3-brush": "^1.0.4",
"d3-color": "^1.0.3",
"d3-force": "^1.1.0",
"d3-format": "^1.2.0",
"d3-hierarchy": "^1.1.5",
"d3-interpolate": "^1.1.5",
"d3-scale": "^1.0.6",
"d3-selection": "^1.1.0",
"d3-shape": "^1.2.0",
"d3-time-format": "^2.1.0",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26",
"bootstrap": "4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.11.0",
"@angular/cli": "~7.1.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~3.1.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"ng-packagr": "^4.2.0",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~7.0.0",
"tsickle": ">=0.29.0",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"tslint": "~5.11.0",
"typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```