# Build:Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting error like this

```
**Build:Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>** .
```

I have installed TypeScript 2.4.1 and downloaded angular quick starter files from git [angular quick starter files](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) and copied  **src folder , bs-config.json, package.json , tslint.json files** to the project (I have created one empty template project in ASP.NET MVC). While rebuilding I'm getting this error. What to do?

Comment: There was a conflict last month caused by rxjs... Update that package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rxjs/Subject.d.ts error : Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793859/rxjs-subject-d-ts-error-class-subjectt-incorrectly-extends-base-class-obs)

Comment: It's a mystery why you would use Angular quick starter instead of angular-cli.

Comment: some one deleted the answer ? what to do ?

Comment: @AverlaTeam sorry i just removed my `assuming answer` as I do not have a time to continue to participate on that atm. @torazaburo The reason I mention that global `tsc` can interferer wit local version as I experienced that long ago myself but seam like it is fixed now. I said that `angular` is not properly compiled with the `typescript 2.4` is based on that issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18454

Comment: The question is a dupe. The starter you are using appears to have RxJS 5.0.1 as a dependency. That is an old version and will effect the error mentioned in the title - and in the dupe target - when TypeScript 2.4 is used.

Answer (score 2):

I have uninstalled TypeScript from the control panel and installed using NuGet.
Now it's working.

**PM => Install-Package Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler -Version 2.1.5**

Comment: If you think that this is the correct answer, you as questioner should check it as the correct one, even if the author is you.

Answer (score 0):

That problem was fixed in RxJS but you should compile it using TypeScript 2.4
Open the .csproj with a notepad and look for this tag

```
<typescripttoolsversion>1.8</typescripttoolsversion>
```

change it to and compile.

```
<typescripttoolsversion>2.4</typescripttoolsversion>
```