# Class extending typescript error: "TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf: expected an object or null, got undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

In my ionic3 app, I have the following pieces of code:

```
@Injectable() // I tried also without this @Injectable and got the same error
export class M_someClass {
  constructor () {

  }

  method1 () { console.log("method1 used") }

}

@Injectable()
export class M_otherClass extends M_someClass {

  callMethod1 () {
    this.method1()
  }

}
```

When I try running my app, I get the following error: `TypeError: Object.setPrototypeOf: expected an object or null, got undefined`

I searched about this, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555756/uncaught-typeerror-object-setprototypeof-called-on-null-or-undefined-after-up) that seem to relate to the same issue. If I understand it right, [from this issue page](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16506), it seem that the bug has been fixed in 2.4.0 or 2.4.1 release of typescript.
I checked my package.json and in "devDependencies" I've got `"typescript": "~2.4.2"`.
So I don't understand why I still do have this error.

Did I misunderstand and this bug might not be fixed in typescript 2.4.2? If yes, is there any workaround to make my code work?
Or could that error come from somewhere else?

Comment: check circular dependency, it help's to me

Answer (score 0):

just change the arrangement of your classes :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

class M_otherClass  {
  constructor(){

  }

  test(){
    console.log('test')
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent extends M_otherClass  {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.test();
  }

}
```

check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrulqi)

**update**:

ok, in your **service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
class ParentService{
  constructor(){}
  get(){console.log('test')}
}

@Injectable()
class ChildService extends ParentService{
  constructor (){
    super();
  }
}

export {
    ChildService,
    ParentService
}
```

in your **component** for using services:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildService } from './app.service.ts'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public childService:ChildService){
    this.childService.get();
  }
}
```

in your **app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { ChildService, ParentService } from './app.service.ts'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [ ChildService, ParentService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

check this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glgycx)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you suggest. The two classes I'm creating are providers, therefore, they need the `@Injectable` decorator, so I don't really understand how using `@Component` could work.

Comment: I've checked it quite deeply and my code is shaped exactly like your suggestion. Trying in stackblitz, it seem to be working there. So I tried updating my ionic in case, running `npm install -g ionic`, but I'm still getting the same error. I'm wondering if maybe I should update something in my app itself.

Comment: @chateau whats up? did you find the problem?

Comment: I took some time to cleanup my whole code to make sure everything else is good. Checking again after that, the problem persists. I ran an npm install on my directory, but no change on that. I don't have much other clues.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if I just have to find a workaround for that bug and just not use class extension. But it'd really be a pity for the quality of the code.